# How to handle the session after closing the browser?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have to  session handle when after closing the browser, I had searched many sites, But did not get any proper steps,

I have a main php.This page has set the lifetime handle session parameter,
below is my code.

```
  session_set_cookie_params('3600');    
  session_start();
```

and my second php page also same code having maintain for session.

session_set_cookie_params('3600');
    session_start();

and also added description  in php.ini page,

```
void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )
```

but still i cannot handle session,so can someone tell me how to make session cookie in php page and require files (or) if you know tell me step of process to make session handle.

**To be simple I need to handle "add to cart" functionality like flipkart in my application. "Add to Cart" functionality will maintain the items added to the cart, if I open the browser after closing it.**

Comment: maybe you can solve with using cookie.

Comment: typically you store the basket into database...

Comment: Use cookies to save a cart_id, and save that cart_id along with the information in the database (`setcookie(....)`)

Comment: Think of 'session data' as 'temporary data' with a lifetime of tens of minutes (maximum lifetime of, say, 30 minutes). If you want to keep track of 'things' longer than that then you need 'cookies'. These can have any lifetime you wish but they need to be 'looked after'. Using 'cookies' may involve 'logging in' to your web-site with the appropriate validation to ensure that the 'current' 'shopping basket' is valid.

Comment: ok vincent i i'll try it.